# Opensmile features shown but datas are not specific

Tags: audio, feature-extraction, audeering-opensmile

I am new to opensmile. I'm using opensmile for extracting sound files in .csv format for my project. In this project I am going to give these .csv files labeled by emotion to an AI that has been written by python so i can train my AI.

But the problem is, I got my outputs from opensmile using emolarge.conf file. (it is giving the same type of outputs in other .conf files.) I have the features but there is no data corresponding to features. All the data shown in the bottom of the .csv file. So i can't delete the features that i don't need and also i can't tell the which feature give which data. Is it normal if im going to give these .csv file to python like this am i going to have a problem?

Im adding the screenshots of the .csv file to be more spesific
[features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilytg.png)
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y43id.png)

And also any information with opensmile that help me in this project I greatly appreciate it..